# What's the Pythonic way to initialize attributes or properties?

Tags: python, object, coding-style

Python supports class attributes, instance attributes and properties.

```
from time import ctime, sleep

class MyClass(object):
    A = ctime()            # class attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = ctime()   # instance attribute
        self._C = None

    @property
    def C(self):           # property
        if self._C is None:
            self._C = ctime()
        return self._C
    @C.setter
    def C(self, c):
        self._C
```

To a user who is not aware, how MyClass is implemented, A, B, and C show similar behaviour:

```
sleep(2)
myObject = MyClass()
sleep(2)
print myObject.A         # prints time module was initialized
print myObject.B         # prints time instance was created, 2 sec later
print myObject.C         # prints time this line was called, 2 sec later
myObject.A = 'foo'       # myObject.A is now an instance attribute
myObject.B = 'foo'       # myObject.B is still an instance attribute
myObject.C = 'foo'       # myObject.C is still an (instance) property
print myObject.A         # prints 'foo'
print myObject.B         # prints 'foo'
print myObject.C         # prints 'foo'
```

From the answer I got here, I understood the following: The first time `myObject.A` is printed, `myObject.A` is `myObject.__Class__.A` is `MyClass.A`. The second time `myObject.A` is not `myObject.__Class__.A`. Fine.

In the example above, `ctime()` was used only to illustrate, how A, B and C differ. Now assume, we are using an immutable constant instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    A = 'bar'               # class attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = 'meta'     # instance attribute
        self._C = None

    @property
    def C(self):            # property
        if self._C is None:
            self._C = 'foobar'
        return self._C
    @C.setter
    def C(self, c):
        self._C = c

myObject = MyClass()
```

`myObject.A` is still the class attribute `MyClass.A`, while `myObject.B` is an instance attribute and `myObject.C` is a property. All of them, do exactly what I want. They have a default value and I can assign some other value. Which *style* should I use, A, B or C?

Comment: Actually, they don't both "work".  They don't both do the same things.  `foo.A` actually **creates** an instance variable, which is found before the existing `Foo.A` class variable.  "Which style should I use" depends **entirely** on what your objective is.  Do you want instance variables or class variables?  Please include your goal in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to initialize a constant class attribute is in the class definition itself.

Looking at the code in the question, it seems that there is some confusion about how to access class attributes from an instance object.

Note that in an instance object you can access class attributes by name because when an attribute isn't found in the internal dictionary, the lookup continues in the class dictionary. That is, if `instance.A` doesn't exist, `instance.__class__.A` will be return instead if it's available.

However, when an attribute is created in an object instance, the the class attribute is shadowed. That is, `instance.A = <value>` creates a new instance attribute and the next time you access `instance.A`, `<value>` will be returned. However, the class attribute can still be retrieved using `instance.__class__.A`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends when you want the initialization to run and what instancing you want.

- If you want a single instance of the attribute (i.e. a single value) shared between all instances of the class, use a class attribute.
- If you want each instance of the class to have a distinct value of the attribute, use an instance attribute.

As an aside, your code samples contain attributes rather than properties.

I can't understand your update to the question. You probably need to step back and explain your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

> There appear to be two styles of creating simple properties or attributes.

They are not "styles" at all, and there is only one thing being done: assignment.

They have different effects.

In Python, the logical rule is followed that stuff declared within the `class` block belongs to the class. Thus `A` is an attribute of the class (roughly analogous to one declared `static` in C++ or Java or C#). `B` is an attribute of each instance, produced automatically when `__init__` is run on the instances.

As for your update, I have no idea what you're trying to ask. Try using real names rather than 'A' and explaining your use case (i.e. **why** you want to do whatever it is).